# Will a custom USB driver improve my application performance?

Tags: c#, performance, usb, kernel, driver

I developed a C# application that reads data from a USB device at a specific rate.  However, if my CPU is bogged down by other programs, then my program cannot keep up with the data coming in from the device and I lose data.

Is it possible that a custom driver could solve this problem?  I would think that the performance of kernel mode code would be more guaranteed then user mode code.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of driver are you using now?  What kind of device is this?

Comment: It's a generic Microsoft HID driver (Windows 7).

Comment: As you have a HID device already, it is likely to not improve matters any. If you have a custom device, consider using WinUSB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between kernel and user mode threads.  Except that you can bump up the thread priority higher in kernel mode.  Try bumping up the user mode thread priority first.  And make sure the read is blocking so that the thread scheduler really likes you when the read completes.  This is otherwise no fix for running out of buffer space when you can't process the data fast enough.